# Vector to represent the position

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> If the velocity vector is $\langle{2t^2+5, 4e^{2t}}\rangle$, and at time $t=0$ the particle is at the point $(-6, 2)$, find the vector that represents the position of the particle at $(-6, 2)$.

I know that the position vector is $x(t) = \langle {2t^3/3 + 5t + c, 4e^{2t} + c} \rangle$. At x(0), the vector is $\langle{c, 4+c}\rangle$.

How do I find x(t) at (-6, 2)?

Comment: This question is really weird, it seems to answer itself.

Comment: Am I missing something? I'm new to vectors so I'm sorry if its a really simple question.

Comment: 'Find the vector that represents the position of the particle at $(-6,2)$' appears to ask you to find exactly the point $(-6,2)$.

Comment: $$r(0)=(c,2+c)$$
what you have written is correct?

Comment: My answer key says $\langle{2t^3/3 + 5t - 6, 2e^{2t}}\rangle$

Comment: Then the question should actually be: Find the position of the particle as a function of $t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the position, up to two constants $c_1$, $c_2$, by integrating the velocity. So you should get:
$$
x(t) = 2t^3/3 + 5t + c_1, \tag{1}
$$
$$
y(t) = 2e^{2t} + c_2. \tag{2}
$$
From the condition that, at $t=0$, the position is $(x,y)=(-6,2)\,$ you get the constants:
$$
c_1 = -6, \qquad
c_2 = 0.
$$
Therefore we get the final answer by substituting the values $c_1$, $c_2$ into $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$
x(t) = 2t^3/3 + 5t -6,
$$
$$
y(t) = 2e^{2t}. 
$$

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now; I integrated incorrectly for y(t).

Comment: That's part of it. Also in your formulas you wrote $c$ - which seemed to be just one number - instead of using a *2-component vector* $(c_1,c_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

See,i gues that u want to find the position vector of the point as a function of time.
If that is the case then,we have the velocity of point as a function of time given as :
           (2t^2+5)i + (4e^2t)j.
Now, on integrating w.r.t. t we have the position vector of the point as a function of time given as :
    (((2t^3)/5)+5t+a)i + (2e^2t +b)j.
Where a and b are arbitary constant.Now to find them we use that at time t=0 they are at point (-6,2).By this we find the constants to be a=-6 and b= 0.
Therefore the position vector of the point as a function of time is given as,
       (((2t^3)/5)+5t-6)i + (2e^2t)j.
Here i and j are unit vectors along the x and y axis.Hope this helps!